# How do I accept client-side files in my program on the fly?

Tags: java

I have a program that processes `.graphml` files and produces XML files. But I want to deploy my project where I will accept `.graphml` files from the client system (upload-files) that produces the XML. For now I'm having my own location as like this.

```
String graphmlFile = "C:\\Users\\file.graphml";
final Graph newGraph = TinkerGraph.open();

try {
    newGraph.io(IoCore.graphml()).readGraph(graphmlFile);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How do I make this possible on the fly?

Comment: "on the fly" is almost a meaningless buzzword at this point. What do you actually mean?

Comment: sorry for that, i mean dynamically allowing client to upload the file and location of that file should get stored in that "graphmlFile" variable.

Comment: "upload", "deploy" - is it web?

Comment: You want to move this code into a server?? And make it accept files?  If so, try using Java Servlets ([`Apache Tomcat`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/index.html)), {or you can use Spring Framework or any other framework }, then you would make an endpoint (a servlet, or if used Spring, a @Controller class), this endpoint just takes the file from the request stream, process it, then send the result as a response (or save it on a local server file, till requested again by the client)

Comment: @user9335240... yes, exactly, but i have no knowlege in servlet kind of thing, can you suggest me any template or something

Comment: Try this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm